# Remove repeated values from permutation

Tags: python

My question is really straightfoward: is there a way to describe all permutations between 10 numbers and exclude repetitions?
In this case, I only have two places to fill in with numbers (English is not my native language, I don't know how you guys call it).

If I do

```
for x in range (1,10):
 for y in range (1,10):
 print(x,y)
```

I will have results like `(3,7)` and `(7,3)`.
Is there a way to cut these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for this. But to do it in the loop, just start your second loop at `x`:

```
for x in range (1,10):
    for y in range (x,10):
        print(x,y)
```

Results:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
1 7
1 8
1 9
2 2
2 3
...
```

With itertools it could look like:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

list(combinations_with_replacement(range (1,10), r=2))
```

Result is similar:

```
[(1, 1),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (1, 4),
 (1, 5),
 (1, 6),
 (1, 7),
 (1, 8),
 (1, 9),
 (2, 2),
 (2, 3),
 ...
```

Comment: That's neat! Thanks a lot!